How to finish basement without future moisture issues
We recently moved into a newly built house (on Long Island in New York) with an unfinished basement and I would like to finish the basement DIY style. Our house is just at the edge of a floodzone and part of the basement is below sewer grade, so I’m a bit concerned about moisture.
In the course of my research I found some people saying one should place a foam board or vapor barrier between the framing and the cement walls of the basement to prevent the biodegradable wood from directly touching the cement, which may get wet. However, others said the vapor barrier may trap moisture against the basement walls and corrode the cement over time.
One person suggested leaving an air gap, instead of a foam pad, between the framing and the basement walls. But I worry that in the event there is mold or anything else to fix inside that gap, the inside would be inaccessible.
What can I do about this problem?

are the walls watertight?

What is DIY style?  Cement will not corrode....don't listen to whoever gave that advice.

Idk what the builders did regarding waterproofing the outside but so far (3months) the walls don't feel damp I don't know if means anything.

I guess this person meant other materials like paint on the wall may corrode. Should I just put a layer of XPS between the cement and framing and call it a day?

A YouTube video I saw suggested putting a French drain all along the wall. But that seems like a bit much-what I meant by diy style i don't wanna do anything unnecessary

French drain is good choice to keep ground water from penetrating te walls

French drain doesn't help at all if there is floodwater outside above the level of the French drain. Since being "on the edge of a flood zone" and "below sewer grade" have both been mentioned, "finished basement without moisture problems" is a very optimistic attempt. I'd strongly suggest leaving it unfinished and with anything stored down there elevated from the floor until you've gone though at least an entire year (and longer if you don't get flooding typical for the area within that year,) or risk an expensive lesson in "Nature wins."
